# which is best practice for creating link for resetting the password?

Tags: php, passwords, forgot-password, change-password

I have users on website and their password are encrypted (md5) and stored in the database. Now, I have their e-mails, and if someone forgot his password, I want to send him link to reset it's password.

Anyone can advise on how this can be done? Which are best practices?

Regards,Zoran

Comment: MD5 is not "encryption", it's *hashing*. MD5 is also not very good hashing.

Answer (score 3):

A secure way to handle password-resets could look like this:

Password reset request:

1. User opens password-reset request form and enters the email address.
2. Your application checks whether the email exists in your database. If it exists it creates a token, which should be random and not derrived from informations like userid or timestamp. A **hash of the token** will be stored in the database in a separate table, together with the userid and an expiry date. A link with the original token is sent to the user per email.
3. The application shows a confirmation that the email was sent. This page can contain the email address, so the user can check if he had a typo (after all there was no information whether the email was in the database, so that an attacker cannot test its existence).

Password reset:

1. User clicks the link and opens the reset form. On this form he can enter the new password twice. The token has to be included as hidden input tag in the form.
2. After submitting the form, the application hashes the token and searches for such a token-hash in the database. If it matches and has not expired, the user can be allowed to change the password. At last the token should be marked as used, i myself prefer to keep the entry, so i can inform the user that the token was already used, when he clicks the link again.

You can hash the token with a hash algorithm like SHA512 without a salt. This is secure if the token is very strong (minimum length 20 with 0-9 a-z A-Z). Theoretically you have to check whether such a hash already exists before you enter it in the database, in practise this is negligible.

Comment: Upps, i have just realized that this is an old thread.

Comment: appreciate the detail and clarity in this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should send an email using `mail()` and add to the db a hashed random string. THe email should contain a link like "domain.com/forgot.php?h=HASHEDSTRING". In that page, you should check which user has that hashed string and output a field for them to reset their password.

Answer (score 1):

Pop a column in the database that is fairly unique and is a randomly generated token string (quite long). When the user requests the password to be reset, send them that token in an email for verification. Returning that token via a link (aka GET) will confirm the user has access to the email address and at that point allow them to reset their password.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows,

1. If user forgot his password allow him to enter email registered with.
2. Send an email with reset password link and the link should contain md5(some data) 
   ex: www.ex.com/md5_data
3. Before sending mail the check email entered is existed, if existed take the user id, store user id, md5(data) which you are sending along with mail
4. When user clicks on link sent to mail get the url data and check if that md5 data exists in your table and if exists get the user id and allow him to set new password and update password using user id and delete the md5 data from table so if he again clicks the link it should not work.